# How to track transactions/events on a specific wallet using ethers.js?

Tags: javascript, ethereum, ethers.js

I want to track all "mint" transactions happening on a specific wallet using ethers.js. I know that you can create a filter, where you track a specific event signature, but I want to track all "mint" events, which can differ in the indivdual signatures.

Currently I have this, but it only tracks a specific event signature:

```js
const filter = [
    ethers.utils.id("Mint(address,uint256)"),
    null,
    [ethers.utils.hexZeroPad(address, 32)],
]

provider.on(filter, (log, event) => {
    // process event
})
```

Mint Events can have different amounts and types of arguments. I want to track all events with the same name ("Mint"), but with different arguments? Any of you know a solution to that?

Is there a way to track all transactions happening on a specific wallet and look up the events emitted from each transaction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The event name is not stored in the transaction receipt - so there's no way to filter **all** events that contain "XYZ" in its name.

The transaction receipt (specifically `topics[0]` of each event log within the receipt) stores the event selector. Which is a keccak-256 hash of the event name and argument types.

For example:

- `Mint(address,uint256)` => `0x0f6798a560793a54c3bcfe86a93cde1e73087d944c0ea20544137d4121396885`
- `Mint(address)` => `0x3c3284d117c92d0b1699230960384e794dcba184cc48ff114fe4fed20c9b0565`
- `MintToken(address,uint256)` => `0xdcdea898caf5576419f89caf69301592a4758349a0bd62300b58849213420a72`

So you'll need to create a list of event signatures (value of `topics[0]`) that you're interested in, and filter against them.

*Note: There's also anonymous events that don't store its selector at all, but this doesn't seem to apply to your case.*

---

> Is there a way to track all transactions happening on a specific wallet and look up the events emitted from each transaction?

Not available with the standardized JSON RPC API. So you'll need to build a collector service of all blocks and all transactions within them, retrieve their receipts, and then pass those that you're interested in to other service.

Or you can use some 3rd party service that does it in the background and simply sends you a webhook or other type of notification when there's a transaction from/to any of the addresses that you're watching.